# Iterate through a file and parse in a bash script

Tags: bash, file, while-loop

I have a file that is filled with Full Names and Username, the file will look like this

```
Bob Smith bsmith
David Miller dmiller
...
```

I could do this one at a time by doing:

```
useradd -c "Bob Smith" -d /home/bsmith -s /bin/bash bsmith
```

But I want to figure out how to iterate through my file with a while loop and use variables maybe to do this. Thanks!

Comment: BashFAQ #1: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
$ while read a b c; do echo -e "first: $a \t second: $b \t third: $c"; done << EOF
> Bob Smith bsmith
> David Miller dmiller
> EOF
first: Bob       second: Smith   third: bsmith
first: David     second: Miller          third: dmiller
```

Comment: Use `read -r` unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise; without it, backslash literals are dropped from your input. Also, any implementation of `echo -e` that doesn't print `-e` on its output is noncompliant with POSIX; safer to use `printf`. (as in: `printf 'first: %s\tsecond: %s\t third: %s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"`). See the POSIX echo spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. how do I specify what file I'm reading through? I could use cmd line args or just have an absolute path to it. And to clarify, the the loop the names will be stored in the variables $a $b and $c? So my command would look like `useradd -c "$a"+"$b"  -d /home/"$c" -s /bin/bash "$c"`

Comment: Correct. instead of `<< EOF ... EOF` use `< filename`.

Comment: `useradd -c "$a $b"`; there is no string concatenation operator. Instead, parameter expansion allows you to interpolate values into a string.